# Why don't \pscircle and \psellipse move the current point before drawing their shapes?

Tags: pstricks

I have tested all PSTricks closed curves:

- `\psframe`
- `\psccurve`
- `\pspolygon`
- `\pswedge`
- `\psellipticwedge`
- `\pscircle`
- `\psellipse`

and I noticed that only `\pscircle` and `\psellipse` do not move the current point before drawing their shapes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\psset
{
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=cyan,
    linewidth=2pt,
    linecolor=red,
}

\everypsbox{\color{red}\bfseries\LARGE}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,7)
\pscustom
{
    \psframe(-3,4)(3,5)
    \psccurve(-3,2)(-1,2)(-1,3)(-1.5,2.5)
    \pspolygon(1,2)(3,2)(2,3)
    \pswedge(-2,0){1}{0}{270}
    \psellipticwedge(2,0)(1,0.5){0}{270}
    \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
    \psellipse(2,-3)(1,0.5)
}
\rput(0,6.5){Default Behavior}
\end{pspicture}

\qquad

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,7)
\pscustom
{
    \psframe(-3,4)(3,5)
    \psccurve(-3,2)(-1,2)(-1,3)(-1.5,2.5)
    \pspolygon(1,2)(3,2)(2,3)
    \pswedge(-2,0){1}{0}{270}
    \psellipticwedge(2,0)(1,0.5){0}{270}
    \moveto(-1,-3)
    \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
    \moveto(3,-3)
    \psellipse(2,-3)(1,0.5)
}
\rput(0,6.5){With \textbackslash moveto()}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Is it a feature by design or a bug?

**NOTE:**

I intentionally put all objects inside `\pscustom` to show the current point effect. I am not talking about how to draw a solid rectangle, a solid polygon, a solid wedge, a solid elliptical wedge, a solid circle,  and a solid ellipse.

### Response to comments

Responding Herbert's comment "it is totally nonsense to use a closed curve inside `\pscustom` which itself creates a closed path", I show an example where closed curves are sometimes needed inside `\pscustom` to make

- transparent holes with other parts are opaque and filled with solid color, or
- transparent holes with other parts are opaque and filled with an image via clipping.

So this scenario is more complicated than just a single simple ring provided by `\psRing`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\psset{linewidth=3pt,dimen=m}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](4,4)
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red]
{   
    \pscircle(2,2){2}
    \moveto(3.75,2.25)
    \pscircle(2.75,2.25){1}
    \moveto(1.25,2.5)
    \pscircle(0.75,2.5){0.5}
    \moveto(2,1)
    \pscircle(1.5,1){0.5}
}
\end{pspicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](4,4)
\psclip{%
\pscustom
{ 
    \code{/clip /eoclip load def}
    \pscircle(2,2){2}
    \moveto(3.75,2.25)
    \pscircle(2.75,2.25){1}
    \moveto(1.25,2.5)
    \pscircle(0.75,2.5){0.5}
    \moveto(2,1)
    \pscircle(1.5,1){0.5}
}}
\rput(2,2){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add `\pspolygon(-4,-4)(-4,3)(4,3)(4,-4)` to show why `\pscustom` is useful (I don't know how to reverse `\psframe`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in the latest `pstricks` so I can simplify the code as follows. For the sake of fun, I illustrate how to apply it for defining an even-odd filling and clipping path.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\psset{linewidth=6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,6)
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=yellow]
{
    \psframe(-4,-5)(4,6)
    \psframe(-3,4)(3,5)
    \psccurve(-3,2)(-1,2)(-1,3)(-1.5,2.5)
    \pspolygon(1,2)(3,2)(2,3)
    \pswedge(-2,0){1}{0}{270}
    \psellipticwedge(2,0)(1,0.5){0}{270}
    \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
    \psellipse(2,-3)(1,0.5)
}
\end{pspicture}


% note that clipping trim the line strokes
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,6)
\psclip{
\pscustom
{
    \code{/clip /eoclip load def}
    \psframe(-4,-5)(4,6)
    \psframe(-3,4)(3,5)
    \psccurve(-3,2)(-1,2)(-1,3)(-1.5,2.5)
    \pspolygon(1,2)(3,2)(2,3)
    \pswedge(-2,0){1}{0}{270}
    \psellipticwedge(2,0)(1,0.5){0}{270}
    \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
    \psellipse(2,-3)(1,0.5)
}}
\psframe*[linecolor=yellow](-6,-6)(7,7)
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your answer is wrong!

Comment: Which part of my reasoning, hypothesis, analysis is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I think, `\pscustom` is the culprit. It wants to draw closed paths. You will get a correct picture if you use `\psset` instead. Because you use absolute coordinates, there is no need for `\moveto`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,3)
  \psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan}
    \psframe(-3,1)(0,2)
    \pspolygon(1,1)(3,1)(2,2)
    \pswedge(0,0){1}{30}{60}
    \pscircle(-2,-2){1}
    \psellipse(2,-2)(1,0.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry. You might misunderstand my objective. The `\pscustom` is intentionally used to show the current point effect.

Comment: I present my bounty to you because I am in hurry to offer another bounty.

Answer (score 3):

You can use all closed curves inside `\pscustom`. But don't expect the desired behavior. There is no need to use closed curves! You can always use the open alternatives, like polygon, arc, and so on.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
 \psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none](3,3){3}}
   \rput(3,3){\includegraphics[width=6\psunit]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
 \endpsclip
 \psframe*[linecolor=white,opacity=0.3](1,1)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why Timothy Van Zandt made the circle and ellipse do not lift the pen before drawing their shapes?

Comment: `\psellipse` _and_ `\pscircle` use the internal postscript function arc and that one is different from all other drawing functions: it doesn't take the current point into account. It needs the center, the radi and the angles. If the center is not the current point then there is _always_ a strait line from the current point to the center of the circle/ellipse if one uses it as part of a path.

Comment: Please consider again the diagram above. The current point (2,0) and and the straight lines go to `(-1,-3)` which is **NOT** the center of the circle and `(3,-3)` which is **NOT** the center of the ellipse.

Comment: the last current point is `(2,0)`. From that point a straight line is drawn to the starting-point `(xCenter+radius,yCenter)` of the next circle/ellipse

Comment: I guess the author TVZ forgot to move the current point to the starting point of the circle/ellipses. I mean he forgot to call `\moveto(xCenter+radius,yCenter)` before drawing the circle/ellipse with the PostScript's arc function. That is why I have to manually call the `\moveto`.

Comment: It was _you_ who used `\pscustom` which _always_ draws a _closed_ path. This has _nothing_ to do with lifting the pen. It is your turn to draw _a correct_ path when using `\pscircle` or `\psellipse` together with other draw function which uses the current point as start point when working with `\pscustom`.

Comment: There are many exceptions in PSTricks that might burden users: For examples: (1) all closed curves have `dimen=outer` by default except for `\polygon` that has `dimen=middle`. (2) all open curves have `dimen=middle` by default except for `\psellipticarc` that has `dimen=outer`. (3) all closed curves move the current points to their starting points except for `\psellipse` and `\pscircle` that do not move the current points. The patterns should be intuitively clear and simple to free users from remembering such things. :-)